# uint(-5.0), where parameter is a float64, = 18446744073709551611?

Tags: go, floating-point, type-conversion, uint

In the Tour of Go, step 13, I changed a bit the script

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var x, y int = 3, 4
    var f float64 = math.Sqrt(float64(x*x + y*y))
    var z uint  = uint(f)
    fmt.Println(x, y, z, f)
}
```

This returns: 3 4 5 5, fine.

But when I do this change: negating `f`:

```golang
func main() {
    var x, y int = 3, 4
    var f float64 = - math.Sqrt(float64(x*x + y*y))
    var z uint  = uint(f)
    fmt.Println(x, y, z, f)
}
```

It responds: 3 4 **18446744073709551611** -5

Why does the **-5.0** being converted to **18446744073709551611** by the `uint` method?

Isn't there something - an algorithm? - trying to check what it is doing beneath?
It's like the `uint` method was brutally casting at binary level from float with mantissa and exponent to an integer?

What is happening?

[image]

If I am misled, and that methods `uint` aren't conversion functions like I believed,
but cast methods like you could find `(uint)f` in *C*,
what is the conversion function that ensure that:

`uint z = anotherFunction(any float64)`

will return the positive integer value of that float number?

Comment: `uint` is not a method, it is a type. `T(x)` is a conversion expression, so `uint(f)` is a conversion that converts the value of `f` to a value of type `uint`. The value range of `uint` is `0` through `18446744073709551615`, note `uint` can't hold negative values, also note the conversion __of non-constant values__ always yields a valid value; there is no indication of overflow.

Comment: So it doesn't convert. It casts, and therefore produce a wrong value. But what is the method that converts, giving the good value: 5 ?

Comment: Officially it is a [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) and Go has no type casting. However feel free to call it whatever you like, just don't expect others to subject themselves to your custom terminology.

Comment: No this is a conversion. There are no type casts in Go. This is just how representing unsigned and signed integers work.

Comment: It isn't a conversion, because Go is unable to convert it. [|-5.0|] in mathematics isn't 18446744073709551611, it's 5. It's sure.

Comment: *"[|-5.0|] in mathematics isn't 18446744073709551611"* -- `uint` isn't a substitute to get the absolute value of a negative number. Absolute value and `uint` are two completely separate concepts. If you want |-5.0| do not use `uint` conversion. @MarcLeBihan

Comment: What should I use instead to convert a float64 to a uint?

Comment: `uint(math.Abs(f))` @MarcLeBihan

Comment: "[|-5.0|] in mathematics isn't 18446744073709551611, it's 5. It's sure." No, this is "sure" only in ℝ or maybe in ℤ. Math is _complicated_.

Comment: If this were really a "cast", the result would be `13840687554816376832`, which is the `float64` bits interpreted as a `uint64`. The conversion _converts_ the number to an integer, then _converts_ it to an unsigned integer. That may seem arbitrary, because it is, as the language needs to make an arbitrary decision how to handle a conversion which is not directly possible. Yes, some conversions may be equivalent to a type cast, but not all.

Answer (score 5):

Value of `f` is a negative number: `-5.0`. What would you expect when you convert this to a value of an unsigned type? Unsigned types have a valid range / representation where there's no room for `-5`.

Go (like most other languages) uses [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent integers. When you convert a signed integer to an unsigned integer, the representation (binary data in memory) is kept, but the number will be interpreted differently.

In general, when converting a negative signed value to an unsigned value, you can calculate the result using:

```
result: MAX_VALUE + x + 1 = MAX_VALUE - ABS(x) + 1
```

So for example when converting `-5` of type `int8` to `uint8`, the result will be:

```
255 - 5 + 1 = 251
```

The same goes for converting `-5` of type `int64` to `uint64`:

```
18446744073709551615 - 5 + 1 = 18446744073709551611
```

(Note: size of `int` and `uint` is platform dependent, on the Go Playground it is of size 64-bit, same as `int64` and `uint64`.)

The last missing piece: your `f` is of type `float64`. Converting `float64` to integer from [Spec: Conversions: Conversions between numeric types:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions)

> For the conversion of non-constant numeric values, the following rules apply:
>
> [...]
>
> 2. When converting a [floating-point number](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Numeric_types) to an integer, the fraction is discarded (truncation towards zero).

So `-5.0` is converted to `-5`, then the above algorithm can be used how this will look like when interpreted as a value of type `uint`.

Comment: So it isn't a conversion, its a casting. A conversion have for goal: returning the same number. If you tell a mathematician -5.0 as a positive integer has for value 18446744073709551611, he won't trust you. What method will you suggest him to use to convert to uint any float number?

Comment: *"A conversion have for goal: returning the same number."* -- Wrong. See [official language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions): *"A conversion changes the type of an expression to the type specified by the conversion."* @MarcLeBihan

Comment: But how do you get the correct value, instead? If it's that one you're looking for, for a calculation? If by the mean of `uint` method Go fails, how do you get the value that 99.9999999% of the humanity would expect, except Go?

Comment: Use [`math.Abs`](https://pkg.go.dev/math@go1.20.4#Abs) to get the absolute value (`|-5.0|`).

Comment: Yes, a `uint(math.Abs(f))` succeeds.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan: A conversion has the **goal** of returning the same value in the new type, but when the goal is not possible (because the same value is not representable in the new type), something else must occur. A cast performs a conversion.

Comment: @mkopriva: The text you quote does not indicate it is wrong that the goal of a conversion is to produce the same value in a new type. It merely says the conversion changes the type, not what it does to the value or what the goal value is.